# JSONstring to Java Object without using any external library

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I m using GWT and want to convert that jsonString to java POJO object without using any kind of external library. can any one help me ..
Any help will be appreciated..
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/
us this way so that you can iterate all value and set it to POJO object...

Comment: thanks for your kind reply.but I dont want to set my POJO objects value manually.It should be done automatically.Is it possible ??

Comment: Yes you can set a all value from json object to POJO object when you are iterate a json data, while as set a attribute value and save once you have to save ...thats it